# Scatter persists after setting X & YData to fewer points

Tags: matlab, user-interface, scatter

EDIT: See end of post for code to automatically reproduce the issue without the mouse/keyboard input and for pictures describing the issue.

Please let me know if any of the following explanation or code requires further clarification.

I'm allowing a user to click on an axis and scatter points appear where they click. Left clicking results in larger scatter markers, and right clicking results in smaller scatter markers. Pressing enter adds a new set (represented by scatter markers switching between yellow and red). Pressing backspace should delete the most recent marker, and consecutively delete markers back through the set and into previous sets if continued to be pressed.

This works fine if I use only one size marker, however, if I allow the size to be determined by the left/right click, then upon clicking backspace to delete previous points, it will correctly delete the points until you arrive at the first point (the earliest point, not the first you try to delete) which had a size change. The still appear on the figure as if they were a separate scatter plot, even though they are one scatter plot, and the data the plot is set from has been deleted (and the scatter data set to that deleted data set).

Here is my example code:

```
function CodeToReplicateIssue()


a = get(0,'ScreenSize');
set(0,'DefaultFigurePosition',[a(3)*.3,a(4)*.1,a(3)*.4,a(4)*.8]);

mainFig = figure;
set(mainFig, 'WindowButtonDownFcn', @mouseDown);
set(mainFig,'WindowKeyPressFcn', @keyPress);

pfTitle = 'Next Set: Enter   Delete Previous Point: Backspace';

colormap('gray');
imagesc(zeros(512,512));
set(gca,'XTick',[]);
set(gca,'YTick',[]);
axis image;
title(pfTitle)
hold on;

cStrs2 = {'r','y'};
pfTracks = {[]};
pfTracksRef = {[]};
pfTrackI = 1;
pfScatters{1} = scatter([],[],5,cStrs2{2});


    function mouseDown(source,callbackData)
        %display('mouseDown');
        pos = get (gca, 'CurrentPoint');
        pos = pos(1,1:2);
        pfTracksRef{pfTrackI}(end+1) = ~strcmp(get(source,'SelectionType'),'alt');
        pfTracks{pfTrackI}(end+1,1:2) = pos;
        if(numel(pfScatters)<pfTrackI)
            pfScatters{pfTrackI} = scatter(pos(1),pos(2),getSizes(pfTrackI),cStrs2{mod(pfTrackI,2)+1});
        else
            set(pfScatters{pfTrackI},{'XData','YData','SizeData'},{pfTracks{pfTrackI}(:,1),pfTracks{pfTrackI}(:,2),getSizes(pfTrackI)});
        end
    end



    function keyPress(source,eventdata)
        %display(eventdata.Key);
        if(strcmp(eventdata.Key,'return'))

            if(isempty(pfTracks{pfTrackI}))
                %do nothing
            else
                refreshScatter('pfScatters');
                pfTrackI = pfTrackI+1;
                pfTracks{pfTrackI} = [];
                pfTracksRef{pfTrackI} = [];
            end

        elseif(strcmp(eventdata.Key,'backspace'))

            if(isempty(pfTracks{pfTrackI}) && numel(pfTracks)>1)
                pfTracks(pfTrackI) = [];
                pfTracksRef(pfTrackI) = [];
                if(numel(pfScatters) >= pfTrackI)
                    pfScatters(pfTrackI:end) = [];
                end
                pfTrackI = pfTrackI -1;
            end
            if(numel(pfTracks{pfTrackI}))
                pfTracks{pfTrackI}(end,:) = [];
                pfTracksRef{pfTrackI}(end) = [];
            end
            refreshScatter('pfScatters');
        end
    end

    function refreshScatter(strOption)
        if(nargin<1)
            strOption = '';
        end
        if(any(strcmp(strOption,{'','pfScatters'})))
            for n = 1:numel(pfScatters)
                if(numel(pfTracks{n})>0)
                    set(pfScatters{n},{'XData','YData','SizeData','MarkerEdgeColor'},{pfTracks{n}(:,1),pfTracks{n}(:,2),getSizes(n),cStrs2{mod(n,2)+1}});
                else
                    set(pfScatters{n},{'XData','YData'},{[],[]});
                end
            end
        end

    end

    function scatterSize = getSizes(indx)
        scatterSize = 9*(pfTracksRef{indx}(:)+1)-6;
    end
end
```

Line 32:

```
pfTracksRef{pfTrackI}(end+1) = ~strcmp(get(source,'SelectionType'),'alt');
```

This is where the left or right mouse button is recorded, later used in getSizes(), with the output used for calls to scatter (or when setting the scatter series SizeData).

I can't figure out why the points created before a size change persist after deleteing the associated data and setting the scatter values to that data. It seems like the first time a size is changed a new scatter series is created.

Any light that could be shed on this issue would be appreciated, and any fixes would be doubly appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: One way to see what I'm talking about is to do the following:

Left click several times (lets say 5), spaced out so you can see them all.

Push Enter

Left click 5 more times, again spaced out, note they are in red (this is a desired functionality for my final product).

Press backspace until all the points are no longer visible. This is the correct funcitonality.

Incorrect:

Left click 1 time, right click 4 times.

Press enter

Left click 1 time, right click 4 times.

Backspace repeatedly (10 times). Note that the first 2 points (1 large and 1 small) from both the red and the yellow persist, even though you have clicked backspace enough times to delete everything, which is what happened when there was no size change.

EDIT: I've added code below that replicates the issue I am seeing using some loops and doing away with requiring mouse and keyboard input.

```
function ReplicateIssueWithLoops()


mainFig = figure;

imshow(zeros(512,512));
hold on;
axis image;

for hh = 1:2
    %two runs, the first works fine, the second fails to remove scatter
    %points from the figure.
    cStrs = {'r','y'};
    tracks = {[]};
    tracksSizeRef = {[]};
    trackI = 1;
    scatters{1} = scatter([],[],5,cStrs{2});

    for ii = 1:2
        %simulates 2 sets
        for jj = 1:5
            %simulates 5 left clicks each
            tracks{ii}(end+1,:) = [256,(ii*6+jj)*20];
            if(hh ==1)  %Simulates all left clicks
                tracksSizeRef{ii}(end+1) = 12;
            else        %Simulates 1 left click and 4 right clicks
                tracksSizeRef{ii}(end+1) = ((jj==1)+1)*9-6;
            end
            if(numel(scatters)<ii)
                scatters{ii} = scatter(tracks{ii}(:,1),tracks{ii}(:,2),tracksSizeRef{ii},cStrs{mod(ii,2)+1});
            else
                set(scatters{ii},{'XData','YData','SizeData'},{tracks{ii}(:,1),tracks{ii}(:,2),tracksSizeRef{ii}});
            end
            pause(0.25);
        end
        tracks{ii+1}=[];
        tracksSizeRef{ii+1} = [];
    end
    trackI = ii;
    for kk = 1:10
        %simulates 10 backspaces
        if(isempty(tracks{trackI}) && numel(tracks)>1)
            tracks(trackI) = [];
            tracksSizeRef(trackI) = [];
            if(numel(scatters) >= trackI)
                scatters(trackI:end) = [];
            end
            trackI = trackI -1;
        end
        if(numel(tracks{trackI}))
            tracks{trackI}(end,:) = [];
            tracksSizeRef{trackI}(end) = [];
        end
        refreshScatters();
        pause(0.25);
    end
end

    function refreshScatters()
        for n = 1:numel(scatters)
            if(numel(tracks{n})>0)
                set(scatters{n},{'XData','YData','SizeData','MarkerEdgeColor'},{tracks{n}(:,1),tracks{n}(:,2),tracksSizeRef{n},cStrs{mod(n,2)+1}});
            else
                set(scatters{n},{'XData','YData'},{[],[]});
            end
        end

    end

end
```

Below are pictures demonstrating how the issue looks on my end. In left to right order the pictures show 1) at the end of the first 10 points, 2) after deleting the first 10 points , 3) after the second ten points (the set with size difference), 4) after deleting the second 10 points (4 remain, the two from each set when the size was first changed).

[image]

Comment: I admit I haven't examined your question thoroughly, but can't `hold on` interfere with your deletion? Or maybe the redrawing behaviour of the axes? Maybe they are gone, but the axes is not redrawn. (I think I mean the `erasemode` property.) Wait, [that was removed in 2014b](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/how-do-i-replace-the-erasemode-property.html)

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? Can you edit in an exact sequence of clicks and button presses that replicates what you're seeing? I'm not sure I'm seeing this behavior in R2015b.

Comment: I'm using R2015a, I'll quick try with out the `hold on`. Edit: getting rid of the `hold on` messed things up: after clicking and pushing enter for a new scatter set, pushing backspace tries to reference a deleted scatter series and throws an error.

Comment: I'll add a click / button push sequence you can follow that demonstrates what i'm seeing.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue with the given instructions in R2015b

Comment: I've added code that reproduces the issue I'm seeing without user input, and added photos showing what I'm seeing. Please let me know if the new code (added toward the bottom of the post) is still not reproducing the issue for you.

Comment: Next time ping @excaza with that comment, otherwise he won't be notified.

Comment: Still does not reproduce the issue in R2015b